# Efficent way to sample and convert arrays of binary data using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a byte array.  It contains 24 bit signed integers stored lsb to msb.  The array could hold up to 4mb of data.  The integers will be converted to 32 bit signed integers to be used in the application.    I would like to hear about possible strategies for conversion and sampling of this data.

One thing I need to do with the data is graph it.  With sequential sampling, I am worried about loosing some of the important peaks and valleys in the data.  I also want to do some calculations to determine the highest and lowest values.

Given what I need to do, are there any algorithms or ways of doing things that will help me achieve my goal quickly and efficiently?

Comment: What kind of array is it? `byte[]`?

Comment: re “among other things”: If you don't tell us what you want to do, we can't tell you how to do it efficiently.

Comment: @rhooligan: can you tell us the type of array and how you store the 24 integers? Why are they 24 bit? Can you convert it to an array/list of regular 32 bit integers?

Comment: @svick I've addressed your questions by editing the question.  When I say "among other things", I haven't figured out what I am going to do with the data yet.  I am mainly looking for some broad ideas on where to start with this.

Comment: What do you mean by 24-bit signed integers?  Are they stored in a byte[] or an int[] (with values from roughly [-2^23 to 2^23])?  It may be important to know the range of the values to know how to aggregate the values, for example if you want the mean (average) of the values, you'll need to know if the sum of all values will fit in a 64-bit int, or if you'll need more range.

Comment: @Andrei The integers are stored as 3 bytes since a full 4 bytes is not needed.  When the data is loaded into the application for manipulation, they're converted to int32s.

Comment: Actual range of data for each integer is -75,853 to 1,039,345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input has to be 3 byte ints, then you can convert to 4 byte ints as follows:

```
byte[] input = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; //sample data
byte[] buffer = new byte[4]; //4 byte buffer for conversion from 3-> 4 byte int
int[] output = new int[input.Length / 3];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < input.Length; i += 3, j++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy(input, i, buffer, 0, 3);

    int signed32 = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

    output[j] = signed32;
}
```

*Edit*

Fixed block copy for little endian.

Comment: What I am looking to do is really avoid all this looping.  Given the worst case scenario, this loop could potentially execute over a million times.

Comment: Do you need the absolute min and max, or is sampling good enough?

Comment: I was thinking what I'd do was sample maybe one to five hundred points of data and graph that.   Then the user could zoom in on the graph and get a more detailed sample of data.  My concern is that I might miss some important data features if I just sampled sequentially.  With this particular data set, there could be spikes and dips and this is important to see.

Comment: @rhooligan, if you want to get exact look at the data (like finding out the minimum) you would need “all this looping” anyway.

Comment: I ended up doing something pretty similar to this.  There really seems to be no magic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to convert the `byte` array to an `int[]`. That way, you can work with it easily and today's computers can work with 32-bit integers much better than if you had to work with bytes that represent 24-bit integers all the time.

Comment: Were you suggesting I use BitConverter for this? The bit converter is looking to take 4 bytes to convert to an int so the resulting numbers would not be correct since I am only using 3 bytes to store them.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can't use `BitConverter` directly to do what you need, but the code is simple enough to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the regular sized ints.
Storage is cheap (especially if you only need ~4MB of data) and if you are going to convert them to int32's for manipulation it's better if they're in that format from the beginning.

If the conversion will actually produce another array of int32s then you've just doubled the memory footprint. If you convert individual elements you've just increased execution time.

Best use the native int size.

Comment: Each log entry could be up to 4mb.  Most will probably be much smaller.  There could however, be hundreds of thousands of logs so the data will eventually start to add up.  There is definitely a benefit to storing less data in the scenario.

Comment: @rhooligan: Don't load all of them in memory at the same time. The data in memory should be in the format it will be used most often. The CPU cache will not be able to optimize the access to the 24 bit array if you need to convert each element for use.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to implement and for future developers to understand if you use the bytes directly (3 at a time).

```
// If you're reading from a file, you don't have to read the whole array.
// Just read a large chunk (like 3 * 1024) bytes at a time (so it's divisible by 3).
byte []  data = new []{1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9};
int []  values = new [data.Length /3];
int min = int.MaxValue;
int max = int.MaxValue;

for (int i = 0,j = 1; i < data.Length - 2; i += 3, j++)
{
   byte b1 = data[i];
   byte b2 = data[i+1];
   byte b3 = data[i+2];
   // Are we dealing with 2's compliment or a sign bit?  Let's assume sign bit.
   int sign = b3 >> 7 == 1 ? -1 : 1;
   int value = sign * ((int) (b3 <1)>1)<<16 + b2 << 8 + b1;
   values[j] = value;
   max = max > value ? max : value;
   min = min < value ? min : value;
}
```